# I have trouble using the offsetX and offsetY properties on `mousemove` events

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, mouseevent, offset

I'm trying to go further in JS learning by making a chess game.

I made a 800*800 canvas in which I placed 16 SVG

Then I added event listeners for mousedown, mousemove and mouseup to make the pieces draggable.

Everything is fine except for the mousemove part. I already set an offset at half the image dimensions so the cursor is at the center of the image when moving it, and it works fine as long I run the page at fullscreen. However, if I reduce the window size and move the scroll bar, the image position is off.

Heard about the offsetX and offsetY properties, and I tried to use them. But I think I'm doing it wrong because all I can achieve is make the image teleport everywhere when moving my mouse.

Here's a short, quick to test, version of my code :

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Chess</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="container" style="position:relative;">
            <div id="gameBox" class="game">
                <canvas id="board" width="800px" height="800px" style = "position:absolute;z-index=-1"></canvas>
                <img id ="brook1" src="assets/piecebrook.svg" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" draggable="false"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utility.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
class ChessGame {
    constructor () {
    this.b = document.getElementById("board");
    this.c = document.getElementById("gameBox");
    this.bContext = this.b.getContext("2d");
    this.bContext.fillStyle = "#825e2b";
    this.bContext.lineWidth = "5";
    this.pieces = [];
    this.selectedPiece = null;
}

    
    addListeners = function() {
        this.c.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            eventOnMouseDown(document.elementFromPoint(x,y));
    }, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', eventOnMouseUp, false);
    }
    
    fillBoard = function() {
        this.bContext.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
        var fill = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            fill = (fill) ? false : true;
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                this.bContext.beginPath()
                {
                    this.bContext.fillStyle = (fill) ? "#76521f" : "#ffffff";
                    this.bContext.fillRect(j * 100, i * 100, 100, 100);
                }
                fill = (fill) ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }
        
    startGame = function() {
        this.fillBoard();
        this.generatePieces();
        this.addListeners();
        var obj = document.getElementById("brook1");
        this.pieces[id] = obj;
    }
}

    
eventOnMouseDown = function(elem) {
        if (elem.id != "board") {
            var piece = game.pieces[elem.id];
                game.selectedPiece = document.getElementById(elem.id);
                game.selectedPiece.style.zIndex = "50";
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', movePiece, true);
        }
    }
eventOnMouseUp = function(event) {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', movePiece, true);

    }
movePiece = function(event) {
        let offsetX = game.selectedPiece.width / 2;
        let offsetY = game.selectedPiece.height / 2;
        game.selectedPiece.style.top = (event.clientY - offsetY) + 'px';
        game.selectedPiece.style.left = (event.clientX - offsetX) + 'px';
    }

var game = new ChessGame();
game.startGame();
```

The SVG i'm using :
https://svgshare.com/s/zMV

Tried with and without offsets, tried to use event.OffsetX, event.LayerX, and event.Left but all of them ended messing with the movement. What I'm expecting is for the image to stay on the cursor even if I resize the window

Comment: btw, why is the path wrapped in a block `{ this.bContext.fillStyle ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, found the simplest solution that worked for me.
The picture is in the center of the cursor during movement

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

you should hide the scrollbars on the page so you don't have to take into account scrollLeft and scrollTop, it can also be called offsetLeft and offsetTop. The css property `overflow: hidden;` is responsible for this. If you do want to keep the scrollbars, you will need to take into account the offset of the canvas element itself, it may also have other properties that can affect the cursor location

```
movePiece = function(event) {
        let offsetX = game.selectedPiece.width / 2;
        let offsetY = game.selectedPiece.height / 2;
        let winY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        let winX = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
        game.selectedPiece.style.top = (event.clientY - game.selectedPiece.offsetParent.offsetTop + winY - offsetY) + 'px';
        game.selectedPiece.style.left = (event.clientX - game.selectedPiece.offsetParent.offsetLeft + winX - offsetX) + 'px';
}
```